# Finding shortest cycles containing two nodes

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, dijkstra

Let G=(E,V) be a directed graph with non-negative edge costs. Let s be a vertex. I need to find an algorithm that finds for **each** vertex v, the shortest cycle that contains both s and v. The cycle may contain the same edge several times.

The obious solution is to run Dijkstra from s in order to find the shortest path from s to each v. Then, from each v to run Dijkstra again in order to find the shortst path from v to s. The shortest cycle is the combination of the two.

This works but will take O(|V||E| + |V|^2*log|V|). Is there a better solution?

Comment: I think this question is better suitable for a Math forum.

Comment: Yes, there's a solution that runs Dijkstra twice.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MichelKeijzers This is very much a Computer Science question, it *might* be better suited for [cs.se], but these questions fit on [so] as well. It doesn't *sound* like a [math.se] question, but I could very well be wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For directed graph, you can use [Floyd-Warshall Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) to find shortest path between all two pairs.

Or a more efficient solution could be to run Dijsktra on the *reversed graph* (`G'=(V,E')` such that for each `(v,u)` in `E`, `(u,v)` is in `E'`), and concat the two solution (one in reverse of course). **This is basically running Dijkstra twice.**